# How do i gather API Data from a URL?

Tags: java, json, api, url

basically i have a Link [to a API](https://api.hypixel.net/player?key=6493c7d9-3b2d-48cf-a949-1819d8f1ad37&name=Technoblade) which basically only displays a huge JSON file of stats, how can i  grab the value of "winstreak" found under player.stats.Bedwars.winstreak with Java the easiest?

Input: [Link to API](https://api.hypixel.net/player?key=6493c7d9-3b2d-48cf-a949-1819d8f1ad37&name=Technoblade)
Output: 6

Comment: Whats your problem? How to open a connection? How to read from that connection? How to unmarshal JSON? how to read a value from the unmarshalled  JSON?

Comment: Install Postman https://www.postman.com/downloads/ and then write a program to consume the API.

Comment: mainly having problems with reading from the connection + getting the winstreak value.

Comment: Please consider reading how to ask a question so that we can help you the most effective way possible, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Make a call to your API using an http java client and accept it as a String(JSON). You can then convert that String/JSON into a Java object by using `GSON` library which is used to parse JSON into Java Object or to convert Java Object into JSON.

Usage:

```
String json = `Your API call here`;
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyClass myObject = gson.fromJson(json, MyClass.class);


You will have to create some Model classes which will follow the same structure as your Json.

For Example:
If your JSON looks like  - {"name":"myname","age":8}

Then your MyClass will look like:
Class MyClass{
   private String name;
   private int age;

  //setters & getters
}


If your JSON looks like  - 
{
    "player": {
        "stats": {
            "Bedwars": {
                "winstreak": "your value";
            }
        }
    }
}

Your classes will look like this:

Class MyClass {
@JsonProperty("player")
private Player player;
//setters & getters
}

Class Player {
@JsonProperty("stats")
private Stats stats;
//setters & getters
}

Class Stats {
@JsonProperty("Bedwars")
private Bedwars bedwars;
//setters & getters
}

Class Bedwars {
@JsonProperty("winstreak")
private String winstreak;
//setters & getters
}

Hope this helps.
```